# Derby alter existing column of empty table to be identity

Tags: java, derby, auto-increment, identity

I'm trying the following:

```
psAddPK = conn.prepareStatement("ALTER TABLE users ALTER usr    
                      GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)");        

psAddPK.execute();
```

but get

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "GENERATED"

on create usr is defined NOT NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot Alter the column to re-define it as an Identity, you must Create it as an Identity column from the start. Or you could delete the column and then re-add it as an Identity.

[Here's the Derby Alter table spec](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html#rrefsqlj81859__rrefsqlj37860)

> The ALTER TABLE statement allows you to:
>
> - add a column to a table
> - add a constraint to a table
>     drop a column from a table
> - drop an existing constraint from a table
> - increase the width of a VARCHAR or VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA column
> - override row-level locking for the table (or drop the override)
> - change the increment value and start value of the identity column
> - change the nullability constraint for a column
> - change the default value for a column

**Syntax:**

```
ALTER TABLE table-name
{
    ADD COLUMN column-definition |
    ADD CONSTRAINT clause |
    DROP [ COLUMN ] column-name [ CASCADE | RESTRICT ]
    DROP { PRIMARY KEY | FOREIGN KEY constraint-name | UNIQUE 
     constraint-name | CHECK constraint-name | CONSTRAINT constraint-name }
    ALTER [ COLUMN ] column-alteration |
    LOCKSIZE { ROW | TABLE }
}
```

**column-alteration**

```
column-name SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(integer) |
column-name SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA(integer) |
column-name SET INCREMENT BY integer-constant |
column-name RESTART WITH integer-constant |
column-name [ NOT ] NULL |
column-name [ WITH | SET ] DEFAULT default-value |
column-name DROP DEFAULT
```

**column-definition**

```
simple-column-name [ data-type ]
[ column-level-constraint ]*
[ [ WITH ] DEFAULT default-constant-expression
  | generation-clause
]
```

Comment: Would be nice to be able to alter without having to drop. Not that it matters, but when you drop and then add back the column ends up at the end of the record. Any way to keep it in position 1 without having to drop all the columns?

Comment: None that I can see. Sorry.